# ChatGPT wrapper in python as a command line interpreter

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I've made a command-line interpreter for ChatGPT. It works fine.

My only problem is how you have to wait for ChatGPT's response to be fully finished, before printing the result. I would like it to print the response as ChatGPT thinks. Maybe threading could work?

The following is my code. Nothing special.

```py
import openai

openai.api_key = "MY_SECRET"

while True:
    prompt = input('! ')
    result = openai.Completion.create(engine='text-davinci-003', prompt=prompt, max_tokens=2000, n=1, stop=None, temperature=0.5).choices[0].text

    print(result)
```

I've seen this StackOverFlow post that leads to the same problem as mine.

- [How can i chat with chatgpt using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75351597/how-can-i-chat-with-chatgpt-using-python)

Comment: [here](https://medium.com/@avra42/how-to-stream-output-in-chatgpt-style-while-using-openai-completion-method-b90331c15e85) is a thorough article talking about this exact thing; please let us know what questions you have, if any, that are not answered in that post.

Answer (score 0):

so turns out you have to turn `stream=True` & iterate throw it.

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "MY_SECRET"

while True:
    prompt = input('! ')
    result = openai.Completion.create(engine='text-davinci-003', prompt=prompt, max_tokens=2000, n=1, stop=None, temperature=0.5, stream=True)

    for i in result:
        print(i.choices[0].text)
```